# How do i check that the textboxes and checkbox has been filled and checked before user can submit the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Below shown my JS code and part of the HTML that i wish to create the form. I can't find the reason of why i CAN still submit it when there are fields that are not filled. It should pop up a dialog box according to which fields the user has not fill.

```
<script>
    function validation() {
        if( $('#sdate').val() == null ||  $('#sdate').val() == undefined || $('#sdate').val() == "" ){
            alert( 'Please fill in start date field');
        }
        if( $('#edate').val() == null || $('#edate').val() == undefined ||  $('#edate').val() == "" ){  
           alert( 'Please fill in end date field');
        }
        if( $('#agree').val() == null || $('#agree').val() == undefined || $('#agree').val() == ""){ 
            alert( 'Please indicate that you have satisfied all the requirements');
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="sub-content">
        <div>
            <p>Start Date:</p>
            <input id="sdate" type="date" name="startdate">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-content">
        <div>
            <p>End Date:</p>
            <input id="edate" type="date" name="enddate">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="end-content">
    <div class="center-align">
        <div class="checklist">
            <p>By checking this box I agree that I have satisfied all requirements.</p>
            <input id="agree" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="tick-att">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="align-right">
             <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="validation()" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: put `return false;` after every alert. So It will  stop the execution of submit event.

Comment: if using the code above, added return false; will not work

Comment: @Mandy create a id for the button and using jquery write a code for button click function and add return false to after every alert method. I tried it, it will work see my answer is below. Try that Hope, It will help you.

Answer (score 2):

check box validation was wrong . Iis [`is(':checked')`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjug8bfzpnUAhXMuo8KHdA9BR0QFggyMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fchecked-selector%2F&usg=AFQjCNH6ZPbEuiGrVPpZ-TJKABhamHi6PQ&sig2=9gHTvRXVdyAtMTM9ksUp4w)  .And apply the input validation simple with `!input value` its validate `null`,`empty`,`undefined` .`.trim()` remove the unwanted empty spaces .

if you have `from` tag try with `onsubmit="return validation()"`  instead of `onclick="validation"` submit button. `return false` its stop the function execution when the input fails

```js
function validation() {
  if (!$('#sdate').val().trim()) {
    alert('Please fill in start date field');
    return false // if you have a form tag
  }
  if (!$('#edate').val().trim()) {
    alert('Please fill in end date field');
        return false // if you have a form tag
  }
  if (!$('#agree').is(':checked')) {
    alert('Please indicate that you have satisfied all the requirements');
        return false // if you have a form tag
  }
  else{
  console.log('ok')
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return validation()">
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="sub-content">
    <div>
      <p>Start Date:</p>
      <input id="sdate" type="date" name="startdate">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-content">
    <div>
      <p>End Date:</p>
      <input id="edate" type="date" name="enddate">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="end-content">
  <div class="center-align">
    <div class="checklist">
      <p>By checking this box I agree that I have satisfied all requirements.</p>
      <input id="agree" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="tick-att">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="align-right">
      <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="submit" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</from>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It will help you,

```js
$("#btn").click(function()
{  
        if( $('#sdate').val() == null ||  $('#sdate').val() == undefined || $('#sdate').val() == "" ){
            alert( 'Please fill in start date field');
            return false;
        }
        if( $('#edate').val() == null || $('#edate').val() == undefined ||  $('#edate').val() == "" ){  
           alert( 'Please fill in end date field');
           return false;
        }
       if(!document.getElementById('agree').checked) { 
            alert( 'Please indicate that you have satisfied all the requirements');
            return false;
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="sub-content">
        <div>
            <p>Start Date:</p>
            <input id="sdate" type="date" name="startdate">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-content">
        <div>
            <p>End Date:</p>
            <input id="edate" type="date" name="enddate">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="end-content">
    <div class="center-align">
        <div class="checklist">
            <p>By checking this box I agree that I have satisfied all requirements.</p>
            <input id="agree" type="checkbox"  name="checkbox" class="tick-att">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="align-right">
             <input type="submit" id="btn" class="button" name="submit" value="submit" onClientClick="validation()" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
   </div>
```

You need to add `return false` after every alert. then It will prevent submit event and also it will show the alert message of appropriate field which is first position in the form. If it is not filled immediately the submit event is prevent rest of the alert messages are not shown even the field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

you need to catch the form submit event. The `return false` statement in the if conditions will stop the event. If everything goes fine, no `return false` statement will be executed and the form will be submitted.

```
var validation = function() {
        if( $('#sdate').val() == null ||  $('#sdate').val() == undefined || $('#sdate').val() == "" ){
            alert( 'Please fill in start date field');
            return false;
        }
        if( $('#edate').val() == null || $('#edate').val() == undefined ||  $('#edate').val() == "" ){  
           alert( 'Please fill in end date field');
           return false;
        }
        if( !$('#agree').is(':checked') ){ 
            alert( 'Please indicate that you have satisfied all the requirements');
            return false;
        }
    }

$("form").submit(function(){
  validation();
});
```

Comment: You forgot to return what the function validation returns.

$("form").submit(function(){
  return validation();
});